# Segmentation fault using SDL_ttf to display text to a window

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

This is just a training excersize to get myself working with SDL, ignore the lack of functions, warnings and that everything is in main. I keep getting a segmentation fault, it is certainly what i've done with the section under the `//Initialise TTF, create font pointer, set font and colour then render.` section, as the code without that works fine.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1000;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
// Set up window, surface, image and font pointers
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gImage1 = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gImage2 = NULL;
SDL_Surface* text = NULL;

// Get a window surface, load images
gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "Image in a window, and some text", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);
gImage1 = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);
gImage2 = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);
gImage1 = SDL_LoadBMP("./Image1.bmp");
gImage2 = SDL_LoadBMP("./Image2.bmp");
------------------------------------------------------
//Initialise TTF, create font pointer, set font and colour then render. 
TTF_Init();
TTF_Font* font;
font = TTF_OpenFont("./LucidaBrightDemiBold.ttf", 24);
SDL_Color text_color = {255, 255, 255, 255};
text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "Using TTF to write stuff", text_color);
-------------------------------------------------------
// Apply the image, update the surface with the image
SDL_BlitSurface(gImage1, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL); 
SDL_BlitSurface(gImage2, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL);
SDL_BlitSurface(text, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL); 
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );                           
SDL_Delay(5000);

// Free surfaces
SDL_FreeSurface(gImage1); 
SDL_FreeSurface(gImage2);
SDL_FreeSurface(text);
//  Nullify surfaces
gImage1 = NULL;
gImage2 = NULL;
text = NULL;      
//Close and nullify window          
SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);     
gWindow = NULL;
//Quit images
TTF_Quit();                     
SDL_Quit(); 

return 0;

}
```

I think the problem lies between the `-------`'s.

Comment: Where's your `SDL_Init()` call?  Is `font` non-NULL after `TTF_OpenFont()`?  Where does your debugger say it's segfaulting?

Comment: GCC just says segfault. How do I check if font is non-null? Added SDL_Init.

Comment: Wait, so `gcc` is segfaulting trying to *compile* the code?  `if( NULL == font ) { exit(0); }`

Comment: Sorry, it compiles fine. Then when I run the code `./ text_display` it seg faults

Comment: With `if( NULL == font ) { exit(0); }` it still seg faults and exits. Window pops up for a second then dissappears.